# React Error Boundary non production server?

Tags: reactjs

I am using reactjs and webpack serve and I am trying to get my error boundary to work on my localhost(I know it works on production as I tried)

```
bugsnagClient.use(bugsnagReact, React)
const ErrorBoundary = bugsnagClient.getPlugin('react')

<ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorFallbackComponent}>
    <AppContainer />
</ErrorBoundary>

export const ErrorFallbackComponent =  () => <div>An error has occurred</div>
```

though if I do something like   `throw new Error('test')` in my app container, I see the error in google chrome console but the page does not go to my error boundary.

Comment: It is [by design](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#component-stack-traces). If you want to see in dev, make a build file and then use it with normal http server by using that build.js with a plain index.html or something.

Comment: hmm, I installed iis on my windows 10 computer and did a production build and loaded up my site locally and it still did not show me the error.